# assigning value from js code to mvc razor's hidden field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

if I have inside razor view already defined hidden field like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyHiddenId)
```

how can I populate this from inline js code

```
var someNr = 100;
```

> how to assign this someNr value to m.MyHiddenId property?

Comment: `$('#MyHiddenId').val(someNr);`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add an explicit `id` attribute to `@Html.HiddenFor`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyHiddenId, new { id = "hat" })
```

Then with jQuery :

```
var someNr = 100;
$('#hat').val(somNr);
```

For those who don't have jQuery

```
document.getElementById("hat").value = somNr;
```

According to answers below, without explicit id, `HiddenFor` will set attribute id to `MyHiddenId`. So, this will work too :

```
var someNr = 100;
$('#MyHiddenId').val(someNr);
```

Or without jQuery :

```
document.getElementById("MyHiddenId").value = somNr;
```

Comment: Why not use '#MyHiddenId'?

Answer (score 2):

MVC will give that field an id of 'MyHiddenId'

So for Jquery you can set it as follows:

```
$("#MyHiddenId").val(someNr);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to `assign ID` for you control, By that you know the `control ID at compile time`.

> @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyHiddenId, new { id = "MyHiddenId" })

```
Jquery Code:-
```

> var someNr = 100;
>
> $('#MyHiddenId).val(somNr);

```
JavaScript Code:-
```

> var someNr = 100;
>
> document.getElementById('MyHiddenId').value = somNr;

Comment: Why would you set the `id` to exactly the same value that it already has? `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyHiddenId)` generates an input with `id="MyHiddenId"`

Comment: It's a just example, Why:- Existing Id default name comes from class/model, to hide that or to get some understandable id, we can do this, otherwise we can use model property name as ID :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(function(){
    var someNr = 100;
    $('#MyHiddenId').val(someNr);
});
```

**Note:**

- It's better to perform assignment in document ready as above. This way it's not important where you put the above code, and it's enough to be after referencing jquery; while if you use `$('#MyHiddenId').val(someNr);` directly, it should be somewhere after your html tag creation otherwise it can't see the hidden.
  Also if the value is dependent to any other value or if the value relies on an ajax request setting it in the ready is recommended.
- Since you are using helper, the hidden has id attribute = `MyHiddenId` and you don't need to set it manually.